# CSS text wrapping for IE6+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have the following HTML structure that is generated by a View in a MVC framework.  This HTML structure is repeatedly used on a page to show name-value pairs of a form the user filled out.  It's basically a HTML widget that is being called by the View to display each name-value pair.

For simplification, the original class attribute has been replaced with the style attribute to see the properties more clearly.

```
<div>
  <p>
   <span style="display: inline-block; width: 40%;">Name:</span>
   <span>Value</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

This normally displays like so:

```
Name: Value
```

Currently, if the "value" is too long, the display does this.

```
Name: This value is extremely
too long for me.
```

I want to change this display behavior, so it look like this.

```
Name: This value is extremely
      too long for me. Any 
      longer string simply
      adds to the bottom.
```

The only way I can think of to accomplish this and still work in IE6 is with table tags, but there would end up being a lot of table tags for each name-value pair displayed.  I cannot put the data on the page into a single table tag.  Is there a more lightweight solution in CSS/slight changes to HTML that would still work in IE6?

Comment: You could use a negative text-indent (this only applies to the first line), and then an equally sized margin-left, so the first line would remain in the same place, but the next ones would be pushed right.

Comment: There are ways to handle this, especially with the `float` property, but it would be much simpler to use `table` markup (which wouldn’t really be much longer than the current markup), or `dl` markup. It’s a good idea to use HTML markup that gives an acceptable default rendering, then start fine-tuning it with CSS if needed, rather than use abstract generic markup like `div` and `span` and start wondering how to make things look decent.

Comment: Hi Jukka, as I stated in the question, using table tags means every single time this function was called, it would print out a tiny table tag.  While doable, I'm not sure that this is a "good" idea.  I'll see if that will pass code review muster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="name_value">
<div class="name">Name</div>
<div class="value">Extremely big text</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.name_value { position: relative;  }
.name { float: left; display: inline; width: 50%}
.value { float: right; display: inline; width: 50%; }
.clearfix { clear: both; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53h8J/)

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">Name:</div>
    <div class="right">This value is extremely too long for me.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 200px;
}
.left{
   float: left;
}
.right{
   float: right;
   max-width: 130px;
}
```